# How do I get the height of the following statement - angular.element('<div>content</div>')?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

How do I get the height of the following statement - angular.element('content') ?

I don't want to place it on the DOM, just get the height. Can I do this?
If I have to place it on the DOM first, how would I then get it?

Comment: This is jQuery after all. Check jQuery doc :D

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want to place it on the DOM, just get the height.

You see, this is a thing, we can't talk about height of the content independently of DOM, because what gives text a dimensions is the fact that it is a part of DOM, with some styles applied, being affected by other elements maybe, etc.

So if you need to get a height of the text you need to do following:

1. create empty element, e.g. `div` and append text content in it:

   ```
   var div = angular.element('<div>content</div>');
   ```
2. append this element into DOM, probably setting styles which makes it "invisible"

   ```
   div[0].style.cssText = 'position: absolute; top: -1000px;';
   document.body.appendChild(div[0]);
   ```
3. calculate height

   ```
   var height = div[0].offsetHeight;
   ```
4. remove element if you don't need it anymore.

   ```
   document.body.removeChild(div[0]);
   ```

Comment: I'm trying to recreate the Pinterest style columns using Angular. I'm hard coding my column count to 3 so I need to do the following ...

1. Create an array of 3 items, where each index represents the current column height of that index
2. Determine which column is shortest and then place an element into the DOM in this column
3. Change my array to reflect current height

Is the solution you proposed optimized for this approach?

Comment: Also, why do you append div[0] and not just div?

Answer (score 0):

angular.element is just an alias for the jQuery function. So to answer your question, no, you cannot get  the height of an element without placing it in the DOM. You can't even get the height of an element, if you add it to the DOM but don't show it.

If you want to get the height of an element, you can simply add it to the DOM, get the height and remove it again. This proccess happens so fast users won't notice it.